# Force Paper size in Chrome's print settings CSS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've to print out 2 html pages in a web-app. The first page must be printed out in A5 size , the second in A6 size. I tried to force the a5 print settings with

```css
@media print{
    @page {
        size: A5 portrait;
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

and the a6 print settings in the other file with

```css
@media print {
    @page {
        size: A6;
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

I try to print the A5 page , paper size doesn't change (but portrait mode is set)

Answer (score 0):

add this CSS for A5,
You just have to give fixed size
example A5

```
@media print and (width: 14.8cm) and (height: 21cm) {
    @page {
        margin: 2cm;
    }
}

/* style sheet for “letter” printing */
@media print and (width: 5.83in) and (height: 8.27in) {
    @page {
        margin: 1in;
    }
}


/* A5 Landscape*/

@page {

    size: A5 landscape;

    margin: 10%;

}

        /* A5 Landscape*/
        @page {
            size: A5 landscape;
            margin: 10%;
        }
```

Comment: nothing happend, i need to force change the paper size on Chrome's print settings

Answer (score 0):

You need install a printer driver and add a custom paper size.

It is impossible to change the paper size using css or JavaScript.